# What is the easiest way to practice PHP on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am learning PHP and I'm looking for the simplest way to run practice scripts. I already have netbeans installed.

Comment: Just run them on a browser or a terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install LAMP:  `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`   (be sure to use the caret), it's a breeze (at least in Ubuntu 10.10). Installs Apache and mysql automatically. 
Then open up NetBeans, set the root to the /var/www root folder and off you go! 
I did it not much time ago and it took me 20 minutes in all (if you install phpmyadmin, be careful 'coz sometimes it creates a symlink in /usr/share instead of a link in the root /var/www, that took me most of the time to figure out)

Comment: How do you set it to root? I found the folder on my system easy enough and all it contains is an index.html file. Do I replace this file with the file I am creating?

Comment: According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel the caret at the end is now optional.

Answer (score 4):

from synaptic or from terminal you need to install apache2, php5, phpmyadmin, mysql-server for working with php,then type http://localhost/ in browser it shows "it works"

> "place your php scripts in /var/www folder with an extension of .php"
>   like 'example.php', 'welcome.php'

Answer (score 3):

Install LAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

It includes apache server, php, mysql, even phpmyadmin already bundled. Pretty easy to setup, just follow instructions.

Comment: Ubuntu's already got perfectly fine packages of all of them. apt-get can install them very easily.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install php5-dev mysql-server apache2

password

hit [y]es

go to http://localhost/

write code in /var/www/